# How to read a bundled file from an iOS app using Delphi/Freepascal

Tags: ios, delphi, freepascal, fpc

I have a *.txt file bundled in my iOS app and need to read its content.
I already found this Objective-C code:

`NSString *myFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
            pathForResource:@"MyFile"
            ofType:@"txt"];`

Is there a working Delphi-sollution?

Comment: What do you have in that text file?  can you use property file instead?

Comment: I think this link should sove your problem http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle

Comment: Yeah, i found that page, too. But i need some Delphi Code to do those things.

Comment: OHH.. I Thought you are asking for OBJC code.. ok carry on..sorry for wrong understanding..